# javascript/jquery clearInterval works but with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have a flask-environment running server-sided, which calculates the distance between it's current position (GPS-Module attached to the server) and given coordinates. I want a text to update when a certain event occurs. It should keep updating until a different event occurs.

This is my function to update the distance:

```
function getDistToCurPos(lat, lon) {
        $.getJSON('/getDistFromCurPosToPoint', {
        pLat: lat, 
        pLon: lon,
      },
      function(data){
        dist = data;
        let distStr = String(dist);
        let outStr = '<div class="distanceOutput"> Distance: '.concat(distStr).concat("</div>");
        $( "div.distanceOutput" ).replaceWith( outStr );
        });
};
```

When the start-event occurs, I call the function as follows (with example-values 38 and 9):

```
distRefreshID = setInterval(function() { getDistToCurPos(38,9); }, distUpdateTime);
```

`distUpdateTime` is set to 500. The server response takes 15 ms in average.

Initial state of the text:

```
<div class="distanceOutput">Inactive !</div>
```

To terminate updating the text, I call the following, when a different event occurs:

```
if ( distRefreshID !== 0) {
   clearInterval(distRefreshID);
   $( "div.distanceOutput" ).replaceWith('<div class="distanceOutput">Inactive again!</div>');
   distRefreshID = 0;
}
```

The code works in general. But when the stop-event occurs, I see "Inactive again!" only for a short moment. After that, the text keeps getting updated with the current values for a few seconds.

Any tips, where my bug is ?

Comment: Clearing the `setInterval` won't abort any request(s) that are in progress.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval does not initially call the function, it calls it `after` x milliseconds have passed so if you want to instantly update the content call the function right before setting the interval

```js
getDistToCurPos(38,9);
distRefreshID = setInterval(function() { getDistToCurPos(38,9); }, distUpdateTime);
```